# regex lookahead/lookbehind in posgres

Tags: regex, postgresql, pattern-matching, regex-lookarounds

Using `regexp_matches` in PostgreSQL

Have a text field with contents such as:

```
unique_string_abc
<ul>
  <li>a1</li>
  <li>a2</li>
  ...
  <li>an</li>
</ul>
blah
blah
<ul>
  <li>b1</li>
  ...
  <li>bn</li>
</ul>
blah
blah
<ul>
  <li>c1</li>
  ...
  <li>cn</li>
<ul>
blah
```

Trying to get a list of [a1, a2, a3, ... , an] but exclude b1..bn, c1..cn

So far I was able to get to it using multiple subqueries, with the first one returning the full string between `<ul>...</ul>` and later splitting it by using:

```
SELECT regexp_matches(html_text,
'unique_string_abc\s*?<ul>\s*?(<li>.*?<\/li>)\s*?</ul>',
'g')
```

But thinking there has to be a simpler way using a single regex using lookahead or lookbehind for `</ul>`?

Any pointers would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I compressed it into 2 steps. I think the regex that compressed into single step can be used in only some special situation because of this problem.

> Lookbehinds need to be zero-width, thus quantifiers are not allowed

1. Separate [a1 to an] that contains li tags and exclude [b1 to cn].
   (I inffered the difference between [a1 to an] and [b1 to cn] is the message "unique_string_abc" behind <ul> tag from your regex.)

   (?<=unique_string_abc\s<ul>)[\s\S]*?(?=</ul>)
2. Extract [a1 to an].

   (?<=<li>).*(?=</li>)

Comment: Thanks! That's kind of what I've been doing, was hoping there's some cool and easy regexp to streamline it to one step